# how do you format tool tip so that it shows all of the items on the window

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have over 20 items on the legend and when I hover over the data point, some data points and items are overscrolling the browser window. I need to format the tooltip so that all the items are visible on the window.

This is the part of the tools tip section:

```
tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}<b>',
            valueDecimals: 2
          },
```

any ideas how I could do it?

Here is the sample fiddle page, I need the tool tip to be on top and if overflows the div, I need it to be on the second line and so forth:

http://jsfiddle.net/sean101/LLExL/3326/   [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sean101/LLExL/3326/)

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle to demonstrate how this is failing? Also, is this a Highstock thing?

Comment: @Ondkloss, I've update the post with jsfiddle example.

Comment: Do you mean that tooltip is cut in your container? But in your examples seems to working fine, please explain how we can replicate your issue.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, if you have many items in your legend and you want to show them on tooltip, rightnow, it goes over the div. Some of the tools tip data is not showing. What I need to do is, somehow if the tool tip about to go over the length of the div, I need to show it on the second line and so forth.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, please see the update jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sean101/LLExL/3333/

Comment: See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/G4NLn/8/

Comment: @SebastianBochan, that's good but that's not I really want. Since there are lots of names in the toolltip, it really covers the chart area. I need tool tip to be fixed and vertical and exapnds if it goes over the chart area.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, also, I have set the yaxis title but not showing up on the chart, any ideas?

Comment: In case when you use HTML and CSS, you can replace strict width/height with dynamic, which will be set in the formatter ( <div style="yourstyles">tooltip content</div>)

Comment: @SebastianBochan, any reason why yaxis title is not showing here?  jsfiddle.net/sean101/LLExL/3333

Comment: Increase marginRight value

Comment: @SebastianBochan, is there an example fo useHTML to format tooltip?

Comment: See the docs http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML and related examples.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, I dont see any examples regarding what I need to do here. Here is teh jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/sean101/LLExL/3333

Comment: Why you dont use solution from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/G4NLn/8